# PHP/jQuery - script not working in cell in every row in table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick

I have a table with dynamically created rows. In every row in last column I need a button to Show/Hide invisible row under that row which you pressed button.

I have a code, but button Show/Hide working in first row and next rows without any react.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#show_more').on('click',function(){
            var id_item = $(".btn").attr( "id-data" );
            $('.hidden_row_'+id_item).addClass('hidden_row_sh').removeClass('hidden_row_hide');
            $("#wh_tbl tr.hidden_row_"+id_item).fadeIn(400);
            $(this).hide();
            $('#show_less').show();
        });
        $('#show_less').on('click',function(){
            var id_item = $(".btn").attr( "id-data" );
            $('.hidden_row_'+id_item).addClass('hidden_row_hide').removeClass('hidden_row_sh');
            $("#wh_tbl tr.hidden_row_"+id_item).fadeOut(400);
            $(this).hide();
            $('#show_more').show();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    table.ranking-table, tr, td, th {
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    .hidden_row_hide {
        display:none;
    }
    .hidden_row_sh {
        display:table-row;
    }
    #show_more .sign:after {
        content:"⇩";
    }
    #show_less .sign:after {
        content:"⇧";
    }
    button.btn {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #666;
        width:100%;
        background:none;
        border:none;
    }
    button.btn:focus {
        outline:0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="wh_tbl" class="ranking-table" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col2</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col3</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col4</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col5</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col6</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col7</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++)
    {
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">Text_'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">data_'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">web_'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">xxx_'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">yyy_'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">
                <div id="show_more">
                    <button class="btn" id-data="'.$i.'" >Pokaż <span class="sign"></span></button>
                </div>
                <div id="show_less" class="hidden_row_hide">
                    <button class="btn" id-data="'.$i.'" >Ukryj <span class="sign"></span></button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden_row_'.$i.' hidden_row_hide">
            <td></td>
            <td>col'.$i.'1</td>
            <td>col'.$i.'2</td>
            <td>col'.$i.'3</td>
            <td>col'.$i.'4</td>
            <td>col'.$i.'5</td>
            <td>col'.$i.'6</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: You need to have unique `id` per element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have unique `id` per element, so change `id` to `class` like below:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('.show_more').on('click',function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').removeClass('hidden_row_hide');
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next('.show_less').show();
        });
        $('.show_less').on('click',function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').addClass('hidden_row_hide');
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).prev('.show_more').show();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    table.ranking-table, tr, td, th {
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    .hidden_row_hide {
        display:none;
    }
    .hidden_row_sh {
        display:table-row;
    }
    .show_more .sign:after {
        content:"⇩";
    }
    .show_less .sign:after {
        content:"⇧";
    }
    button.btn {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #666;
        width:100%;
        background:none;
        border:none;
    }
    button.btn:focus {
        outline:0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="wh_tbl" class="ranking-table" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col2</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col3</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col4</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col5</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col6</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">th_col7</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++)
    {
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">Text_'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">data_'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">web_'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">xxx_'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">yyy_'.$i.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">
                <div class="show_more">
                    <button class="btn" id-data="'.$i.'" >Pokaż <span class="sign"></span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="show_less hidden_row_hide">
                    <button class="btn" id-data="'.$i.'" >Ukryj <span class="sign"></span></button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden_row_'.$i.' hidden_row_hide">
            <td></td>
            <td>col'.$i.'1</td>
            <td>col'.$i.'2</td>
            <td>col'.$i.'3</td>
            <td>col'.$i.'4</td>
            <td>col'.$i.'5</td>
            <td>col'.$i.'6</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```